# Separator and freetextfields in comma separated list

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have this list that I use to separate into parameters that are later used as command in an input.

The problem is that one of the fields are freetext and available for users to write in. How can I make sure that I either format the freetext or that I use a separator that can't be used accidentally by the users? Right now I use a comma to separate the commands but I am worried that the users will write a comma and mess up the solution.

What's best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either pick an esoteric / impossible to type character as your separator, or you could use an escape character.

Ie:

```
command|parameter, string  <- Esoteric character
```

or

```
command,parameter\, string <- Escape character
```

Personally, I would opt for an esoteric character, because you can still use simple String.Split functions. You can always check the user's input to make sure they've not included a parameter with the character you're using as a separator.

Comment: What does esoteric character mean? Seems like a good solution if I can use this to split up my commands...

Comment: An unusual character that people are not likely to type - like the pipe symbol, or ~ perhaps. You could also use two characters, which is going to be very unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions. Here is a great tutorial about it http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

You can then do something like this, to verify the users input:

```
var stringToTest = "abcd";
Regex testRegex = new Regex("[^0-9]");
var isMatch = textRegex.IsMatch(strNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

[The MIME standard for CSV files](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) explains how to properly build CSV files that may contain commas:

1. Enclose the values within double quotes
2. If there are double quotes inside a value, double them

For example, assume you want to build a CSV file with the following values:

```
Hello
Well, does this work?
I guess this "kinda" work
```

then the result would be:

```
"Hello","Well, does this work?","I guess this ""kinda"" work"
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up with looks like this, it uses three esoteric characters to minimize the risk och getting mixed up with user input.

```
return string.Format("true|~|eventEdit|~|{0}|~|{1}|~|{2}|~|{3}|~|{4}", variable,         variable, variable, variable, variable);

string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "|~|" };
string[] parameters = PlanningTypeIcon.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(stringSeparators,    StringSplitOptions.None);
```